# Error 99 receiving synchronization data in Genexus Ev3 U9 on Android

Tags: android, genexus, genexus-sd

I'm executing `Synchronization.Receive()` for manual synchronization on Android app in Genexus Ev3 U9 but the process is returning and error 99. Checking Catlog I found the error is happening calling **http://myhost/MyAppWeb/rest/MyAppOfflineDatabase?fmt=json** when I open this address from desktop browser I see the following json

```
{"error":{"code":"500","message":"Ya existe una propiedad con el nombre 'HttpOperationSelectorData'."}}
```

I thought it was a problem related with offline database structure, so I created the offline database again, deleted data from the app on the device, uninstalled it and reinstall it but the problem keeps happening.

What else should I check?

This is the catlog segment where the error happens:

```
08-03 22:36:29.298 D/Genexus-HTTP(23857): Request (POST) to http://192.168.12.178/MyApp/rest/MyAppOfflineDatabase?fmt=json 

08-03 22:36:30.711 E/Genexus-HTTP(23857): Response (500) from http://192.168.12.178/MyApp/rest/MyAppOfflineDatabase?fmt=json

08-03 22:36:30.712 E/GeneXusApplication(23857): Type:System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException.DBMS Error Code:8163.The text, ntext, or image data type cannot be selected as DISTINCT.

08-03 22:36:30.712 E/GeneXusApplication(23857): Invalid sync response from server
```

Thank you

Comment: can you include the catlog when the error happends. It should include more info about the error. Tks.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't found the real problem but It was related to one of the transactions. I exported all the objects to a new knowledge base and started deleting transactions; first those with some kind of warnings, all of them about missing indexes, but nothing too bad. At the end, I deleted a transaction and this solved the problem. So maybe it would be good to know what happened but at least I'd like to share how I fix it.